# replace NA with 0 In R program

Tags: r

I tried to replace NA in the data frame to 0

```
data[is.nan(data)] <- 0     
Error en is.nan(data) : default method not implemented for type 'list'
```

I don't know what the problem is?

Comment: use `is.na` not is.nan : `data[is.na(data)] <- 0`

Comment: You shouldn't do this. `NA` isn't the same as zero.

Answer (score 3):

```
data <- replace(data, is.na(data), 0)
```